# Swift: Set bold using setTitleTextAttributes for range

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

How can I create a button like follows:

[ **Count:** 1 ]

Where Count: is bold and 1 is plain text.

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0,7)
let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)]
leftNameButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 // Where does range go?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish this to work on a UIBarButtonItem you'll need to use a customView like so:

```
let yourString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Count: 1")
yourString.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
let buttonLabel = UILabel()
buttonLabel.attributedText = yourString
buttonLabel.sizeToFit() // Important for bar buttons
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonLabel)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a NSMutableAttributedString

```
let yourString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "[Count:1]",attributes: attrs!])

yourString.addAttribute(attrs!, range: range)

yourButton.text = yourString
```

Comment: UIBarButtonItem doesn't have an addAttribute method.